# Determine which theme location a wp_get_nav_menu_items is for

Tags: plugin-development, functions, menus, filters

Is there a way to determine which theme placement a menu is for when modifying it with the `wp_get_nav_menu_items` filter hook?

I'd like to only add items to certain menus and I don't want to have to depend on the ID or the name of the menu.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this is the simplest means, but you could conditionally add the filter to just the location you want to modify via `wp_nav_menu_args` filter when `wp_nav_menu` is called, then immediately remove the filter so it isn't applied to other menus.

```
function wpa108544_nav_menu_args( $args ){
    // check if it's the location we want the filter applied to
    if( 'primary' == $args['theme_location'] )
        add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'wpa108544_get_nav_menu_items', 10, 3 );

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'wpa108544_nav_menu_args' );


function wpa108544_get_nav_menu_items( $items, $menu, $args ){
    // remove the filter
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__, 10, 3 );

    // do your menu manipulation stuff here
}
```

Comment: To me that seems too much of a hack and creates brittle code. Why isn't the args from  `wp_nav_menu_args` used for `wp_get_nav_menu_items`?

Comment: Brittle in what way? Describe a scenario where this would not work for you. In some cases there are no nav menu args, `wp_get_nav_menu_items` isn't necessarily called via `wp_nav_menu`.

Comment: Brittle because its just a very poor design.

Comment: if you'd care to explain actual, practical issues with it, perhaps we can come up with a better solution.